# Why my app opens empty page and doesn't go to any redirect link after route page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2014

Why my app opens empty page and doesn't go to any redirect link after route page ??
I work on C# , MVC , Visual studio 2010

this is my login action:

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string name, string psw)
    {
        if ((Membership.ValidateUser(name, psw)) == true)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name, false);
            if ((Roles.IsUserInRole(name, "Admin")) == true)
            {
                return this.RedirectToAction("AboutDetails_Admin", "mytask");

            }
            else if ((Roles.IsUserInRole(name, "People")) == true)
            {
                return this.RedirectToAction("TMembersDetails_Admin", "mytask");
            }
            else return View();
        }
        else return this.RedirectToAction("Register", "Default");
    }
```

and this is the login view:

```
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Login";
  Layout = "~/Views/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>Login</h2>

 <form action="/Default/Login" method="post">
  <label>Full Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />

 <label>Password:</label><input type="text" name="psw" /><br />

 <input type="submit" />


 </form>
```

this is my web.config :

`enter code here`

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"      type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,   System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host"   type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,   System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
   </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>

 <system.web.webPages.razor>
 <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,   Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="ttt" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*"   preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
  <compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

and this is my route:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ttt
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", 
                 id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
   }
  }
```

what can I do to make my index page redirect to the login page and not open empty page with http://localhost:1889/Default/Login

Comment: Your question is not clear about "empty page". In case of redirect try: return RedirectToAction("Register","Default",null), in http: "http://localhost/default/register".

Comment: I mean empty pages without any controls

Comment: my master page has the link :<a href="/Default/Login">Login Page</a>  it goes to login page but it is empty with out the form and controls

Comment: Strange to see empty page, can you put a screenshot of the empty page?

Comment: you answer resulted : exception :No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake , 
in the first in visual studio 2015 when I choosed new project It make the the project Authentication : individual by default , so it resultd empty pages when project run ..
when I change authentication (in the first) to No authentication so it works now.